# Can a linear combination of even Legendre polynomials have common real root(s) with a linear combination of odd Legendre polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials, roots

I am using the following definition of Legendre Polynomials: $P_0(x)=1$,  $P_1(x)=x$ and
$$P_{k+1}(x)=\left(\frac{2k+1}{k+1}\right)xP_k(x)−\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)P_{k−1}(x)$$

Let
$b_0>b_1>\ldots >b_n>\ldots >0$ and define
$$f_{2n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n b_{2k} P_{2k}(x)$$
$$f_{2n+1}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n b_{2k+1} P_{2k+1}(x)$$

**Q1**: Prove that  $f_{2n}(x)$ and $f_{2n+1}(x)$ have no common real root.

**Updated with the second question!**

Let
$b_0>b_1>\ldots >b_n>\ldots >0$ and define
$$q_{2n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n \left(-1\right) ^k b_{2k} P_{2k}(x)$$
$$q_{2n+1}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(-1\right) ^{k+1} b_{2k+1} P_{2k+1}(x)$$
**Q2**: Prove that  $q_{2n}(x)$ and $q_{2n+1}(x)$ have no common real root.

The second one is probably a lot harder than the first one.

Comment: It seems to be nontrivial to show that 0 is not a common root; it can be if the $b_i$'s are not strictly decreasing.

Comment: You are right. $x=0$ is not a common root because $b_i$'s are strictly decreasing.  The $b_i$'s are constants in this example and they are not the parameters we can freely adjust.

Comment: For second question, numerical results in Mathematica showed that $p_4$ has 6 real roots and $q_4$ has 5 real roots and there is no common real root.